# With Windows XP, how would I download and burn a 4Gig file?

Tags: 32bit-64bit

I am trying to use my PC to download CentOS 6.4 64bit, for the purpose of burning it to CD, so that I can install that CD on a new Linux server.  I am required to use the 64bit version of CentOS.

Using my Windows XP PC, I browse to a CentOS download mirror site
http://mirrors.usc.edu/pub/linux/distributions/centos/6.4/isos/x86_64/

I think the files I want are

```
CentOS-6.4-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso  4.1G    
CentOS-6.4-x86_64-bin-DVD2.iso  1.4G
```

I downloaded these files successfully, but when I try to burn the first iso file to a CD, my PC crashes with the blue screen of death.  Im guessing the reason it crashes is that my Windows XP, which is 32 bit, cannot handle a 4.1G file.

How do I make this CD?

Comment: CD's only hold ~800MB, so you're going to need a DVD±R(W) if you want to burn that ISO. I'd recommend using [ISO Recorder](http://alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm) to burn the DVD. This has nothing to do with 32bit or 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, this is not related to your operating system bit(32 or 64 it doesnt matter), you're on wanting to burn this image to a CD

i think i didnt need to re-instruct the procedure again you can see this link for Burning your centos image to a CD

here: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/CD_burning_howto.html